# How to check who installed what in the system?

Tags: apt, logging

How can I know:

1. What packages were installed in the system?
2. The user who installed them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check your package selections (install packages) using:

```
dpkg-query -l
```

Read more: https://wiki.debian.org/ListInstalledPackages

@mook765 stated that "You could find out which user requested an install by checking in `/var/log/apt/history.log` and related archives `/var/log/apt/history.log.#.gz`"

Comment: You could find out which user requested an install by checking in `var/log/apt/history.log` and related archives `/var/log/apt/history.log.#.gz`, you may include that in the answer...

Comment: You should clean this answer up, it is a mess, what is with the crossed out lines? -1

Answer (score 4):

how far back do you want to go?

check this log:

```
grep " install " /var/log/dpkg.log
```

the one before:

```
grep " install " /var/log/dpkg.log.1
```

or archive:

```
zgrep " install " /var/log/dpkg.log.2.gz
```

Now that you have timestamps, check against this list's timestamps:

```
grep sudo /var/log/auth.log
```

(you can actually just do it all from this last command)

But, if you have a lot to sort through...its easier to know what times you are looking for by checking dpkg logs.

Comment: hmmm... good thinking. A script could do this detective work maybe...

Comment: Can you write it? :)

Answer (score 2):

Some commands to get this info from the logs suggested by others, to save sifting through the entire logs

```
zgrep -B1 Install /var/log/apt/history*
```

sample of output:

```
/var/log/apt/history.log.4.gz:Requested-By: zanna (1000)
/var/log/apt/history.log.4.gz:Install: powertop:amd64 (2.8-1build1)
```

or

```
zgrep 'sudo.*install ' /var/log/auth*
```

sample of output:

```
/var/log/auth.log.3.gz:Sep 18 07:09:28 monster sudo:    zanna : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/zanna/Downloads ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt install jq
```

`tee` or `>` out to a file for easier browsing, eg

```
zgrep -B1 Install /var/log/apt/history* > ~/install.log
```