# How can I find files that I have modified?

Tags: command-line

I am looking for files that I personally have edited. If it helps, I've used Sublime Text for editing. I have a brand new computer with setup issues, and I'm trying to retrace my steps to see if I've edited something that I shouldn't have.

I've seen this: [Show recent modified/created files using Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411462/show-recent-modified-created-files-using-terminal) but those files could have been changed by anything.

Comment: What kind of "setup issues"? are you looking for personal configuration files that you may have modified, or system files?

Comment: Problems for graphics related issues. Can't change brightness, blank screen on wakeup. I'm not sure what types of files I've modified. A smattering of whatever I've found online as potential fixes for several problems.

Answer (score -1):

This could help

https://askubuntu.com/a/832816/602526

Cleaned up:

Grep is pretty powerfull.

how far back do you want to go?

```
grep sudo /var/log/auth.log
```